# USB-stick not visible in BIOS-menu

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bios

I tried to format my harddisk and want to install windows 7 on the Computer, but my bios doens't give me the option to boot from my usb stick.
I tried it on an older lenovo laptop and there I can choose the stick as a boot device in the boot sequence. Any suggestions ?
Thanks!

**
bios-version/date: American Megatrends Inc. V5.7, 30.08.2010 SMBIOS-version: 2.5 bios-version: NEC - 20100830 baseboard: P43i (MS-7519)
**

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer?

Comment: Is it UEFI?
Then you probably have to have a bootable UEFI stick plugged in to make the option appear. Otherwise, I assume it's not possible. But anyway, as @DavidPostill said, give us the model.

Comment: i bought hardware and put it all together so its not bought in one piece

Comment: Then at least the motherboard and bios information

Comment: How do i get it UEFI? In the formating preferences it says NTFS or FAT32 if that fits to ur question. Sry havent got that much knowledge about this section.

Comment: [edit] the question and include the output from `wmic bios get biosversion, manufacturer, name` and `wmic baseboard get product, Manufacturer, version, serialnumber`

Comment: Oh, you misunderstood me: Is the BIOS a 'legacy BIOS' or UEFI?

Comment: in the preferences under volumes it says MBR - Master Boot Record so it's Bios right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your BIOS does not support booting from a USB drive, you could try installing the [Plop Bootloader](http://plop.at/). It will add a entry to your boot menu where you can boot from a USB.

Comment: downloaded it and tried to install but couldnt figure out how

Comment: @Nic48 What operating system?

Comment: @Nic48 On windows, you can run plpbt-5.0.15.zip/plpbt-5.0.15/Windows/InstallToBootMenu.bat as administrator. On Linux, run `sudo apt-get install grml-rescueboot` and then extract the directory, and copy plpbt.iso to /boot/grml  , and then run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: finally it works, u re my hero man :D thank you! Thanks to the rest as well;)

Comment: @Nic48 No Problem.